# How to see working changes on vscode source control

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, diff, git-diff

Really keen to find out if there is a way to compare an editable panel on vscode to what is on another git branch i.e. what the diff is locally to that on origin master / another branch... but not in 'read-only' mode.

Ideally on the source control extension, under branches i would like to see a list of changed files and click on them, to open two panels one with the branch i select and one with working changes / editable.

Any idea how to do this? I am sure i used to be able to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately for me I'm stuck with an older version of Git and so GitLens will not work on our system. Looks like I will need to keep another folder for duplicate code and checkout branches that have code I need and then use something like MELD to compare and edit between the working file and the 2ndary folder codebase. So far this is the end of my 1st week using VSCode coming from IntelliJ and I am not a fan of VSCode.

Comment: @Elijah you will learn to love vscode - especically if mostly on JS / TS - its flexibility is its strength, you can customise everything, I have found it better than webstorm etc. When i am forced to work on php most people use phpstorm but vscode is where i am most comfy now. Takes a while to get comfy, buts its good because of the extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repositories view of git lens in the source control extension.... hidden by default.... check setting of gitlens in vscode. Branches etc won't show working changes, but repositories view does...